# use the same Jenkinsfile for several github repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 40-50 github repositories , each repo contain one maven job.

I want to create multibranch pipeline job for each repository.

can I use **the same Jenkinsfile** for all projects **without add Jenkinsfile for each  repository**. (take it from another SCM repo) ?

I know that I can use shared library to create a full pipeline , but I prefer something cleaner.

Comment: Just wondering why shared library is not a cleaner.

Comment: Hi  , since I have to add an identical Jenkinsfile to 40-50 repositories instead add a link to correct jenkinsfile in the job level and keep the repositories clean.

Comment: You can check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874987/jenkins-trigger-the-same-job-from-different-bitbucket-repositories/58879416#58879416

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, **I would suggest to create a pipeline with two parameters** and pass the values based on the repo to build. 1) **GIT BRANCH** - to build and deploy required branch

2) **GIT URL** - to provide the git URL to checkout the code.

Providing a reference template.

```
node('NODE NAME') 
{ 
    withEnv([REQUIRED ENV VARIBALES]) 
    {   withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS ID', passwordVariable: 'PW', usernameVariable: 'USER']]) 
        {   try 
                {   stage 'Build' 
                        checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: gitbranch]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
                                  extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS ID', 
                                  url: 'GIT URL']]]

                                ****
                                MAVEN BUILD
                                ****

                    stage 'Docker Image build & Push'
                                *****
                                DOCKER BUILD AND PUSH TO REPO
                                *****
                }
              catch (err) {
                notify("Failed ${err}")
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }

                stage 'Deploy to ENV'

                *****
                DEPLOYMENT TO REQUIRED ENV
                *****

                notify('Success -Deployed to Environment')

                catch (err) {
                 notify("Failed ${err}")
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                } 
        }   
    }
}

def notify(status)
{
****
NOTIFICATION FUCNTION
****
}
```

Link the Jenkinsfile in the pipeline job and provide the values- build with parameters, while building the Jenkins job.

Hope this helps.