# Jenkins: trigger the same job from different BitBucket repositories

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have 50+ repositories in a BitBucket project and I want them to execute the same job when a commit is pushed (that is maven build and deploy to artifactory). I tried to create a Maven job and make it work, but that can be linked to only one repository. I also tried installing the Bitbucket Team plugin and creating a project with it, and I think this could lead to a solution. In fact I saw that it scans automatically all the repositories with a JenkinsFile in it, so I thought that I could create a common Pipeline on jenkins and call this pipeline from every JenkinsFile in every repository. The problem is that I still have to create a JenkinsFile for each repository, and I don't want to do that. Is there anyway that I can trigger the same Jenkins job from all my repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Remote File Plugin for this. 
What you need to do is,

- Create a separate repository and put your Jenkins file into it.
- Define this repository and Jenkins file in the Remote File section of the BitBucket Team Project configuration page.

This way, for every repository in your BitBucket, this Jenkins file will be run.

Hope this helps.

You can find the example screenshot below.

[image]

You can find it under Project Recognizers

[image]

Comment: It works but unfortunately the plugin can be assigned only to a Multibranch Pipeline, so It's useful to share pipeline between branches, not project. Do you know if there is any way to use it with a Bitbucket Team project?

Comment: Interesting. The screenshot I uploaded from the configuration page of BitBucket Team Project. I will try to upload screenshot of the whole page.

Comment: Where did you find it exactly? In the Multibranch Pipeline on Build Configuration->Mode>By Remote File Plugin. I don't see any Build Configuration in the Bitbucket Team Project. May I need to install any other plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It is under the Project Recognizers

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Please accept my edits to your previous answer, so that I can accept it. It would be better to have a complete final answer rather than splitted into two